# Most efficient way to convert a list of counts to a list of numbers

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have a list of counts where each index represents a number and its count represents how many of that number is in the list:

```
a = [3,5,1,2]
```

turns into

```
b = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3]
```

I was thinking we could do something like:

```
b = []
for ix, el in enumerate(a):
    b.extend([ix]*a[ix])
print(b)
```

But if I am not mistaken it takes k (count val) time to put it in list b as the extend takes k time, but it also has to be done n times giving us a runtime of n*k where n is the number of indicies and k is the number of counts for each index

Another idea is instead of having an array of counts we can have an array of the pure elements:

```
a = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[2],[3,3]]
```

but to flatten it it still takes quite some time (I believe n*k time)

```
b = [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]
```

is there a way to make this more efficient? Maybe converting to string removing all brackets and converting back into a list?

Comment: This will not solve your problem, but note that `a[ix]` is what `el` is. that is why you used `enumerate`, so you might as well take full advantage.

Comment: Try this `sum(([i]*n for i,n in enumerate(a)), [])`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget what is the runtime for this?

Comment: In terms of time complexity this is always going to take an order of `n*k` because that's how many items being generated in the output list. You can at best optimize your code or switch to a higher-performing language or framework but you won't be able to work around the time complexity of `n*k`.

Comment: @yatu numpy is okay there is the flatten function, but I have no idea what the runtime on that is?

Comment: I suggest you use an explicit for loop instead of the `*` operator. This will make it easier to analyze the run time complexity.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks! This makes sense, I was just curious if there was a more efficient method in-terms of time complexity.

Comment: @Kevin no idea. That's why I posted it as comment, rather than an answer

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thank you! Its no problem, was just wondering if there was a way to speed this up!

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy's [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for a performant approach:

```
np.repeat(np.arange(len(a)), a)
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
```

---

Here are the timings -

```
a_large = np.concatenate([a]*10_000, axis=0)

def op(a):
    b = []
    for ix, el in enumerate(a):
        b.extend([ix]*a[ix])

def yatu(a):
    np.repeat(np.arange(len(a)), a)

%timeit op(a_large)
# 17.1 ms ± 422 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit yatu(a_large)
# 368 µs ± 1.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Could you possibly give the runtime of this?

Comment: My guess is that in terms of O notation there is no difference @kevin Though you will notice a big improvement in performance since all logic is run down to c level with numpy

Comment: okay, thats what I figured, I am not looking for 'raw' speed but more for its O notation efficiency. But your suggestion works!